# Can I map sequelize entity to the data base view?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a following problem. I get view in MySQL database. How can I map sequelize entity to this view?

---

Now I found only two solutions:

1. Use raw SQL query to the db like:
   `db.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM dbName.vieName').success(function(data){...}`
2. And using materialized view. I create the table, add triggers in the using in initial view                                               tables and map created table to separate entity.

Maybe anybody solve this problem in the another way? Have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We used #1 and it works fine. I would caution you against Materialized Views in Postgres 9.3. Until REFRESH VIEWS CONCURRENTLY is implement in 9.4 this fall, refreshing your views causes them to lock up until complete.